# Replace part of uri with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to replace get parameter with mod_rewrite in .htaccess. I have Url `www.domain.at/success?id=12345` and need to replace `"id"` with `"vid"` -> `www.domain.at/success?vid=12345`

This replacement must only work on "success" page/uri, but not on other pages of website.

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)success?id=([^0-9]*)$ /$1success?vid=$2 [R=301,L]
```

But this is not working on dynamic part?

Thanks for help!
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to match query parameters in `RewriteCond` separately from request URI like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^success/?$ /$0?vid=%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is not working. Maybe because parameter looks more like id=CFC80AD.prod01-vm